# Haskell type class hierarchy in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, haskell, hierarchy, typeclass

I write a [library](http://code.google.com/p/highj/) with Java interfaces resembling Haskell type classes, and abstract classes implementing all "derivable" methods (e.g. `Monad.join` can be written using `>>=` and `return`). This is my planned structure ([] means the interface doesn't exist yet):

```
                      Applicative <= Alternative <-,     
Functor <= Pointed <= Applicative <= Monad <= MondPlus
Functor <= Copointed <= Comonad      Monad <= [MonadFix]

Category <= Arrow <= ArrowChoice   
            Arrow <= [ArrowApply]
            Arrow <= [ArrowLoop] 
            Arrow <= [ArrowZero] <= [ArrowPlus]
Bifunctor
```

- Is this hierarchy "correct"?
- Particularly, is it correct that MonadPlus implements Alternative?
- Should I split MonadZero from MonadPlus? Same question for ArrowZero and ArrowPlus
- How can I reduce code duplication when a class implements multiple "endpoints" (e.g. Maybe is a MonadPlus and a MonadFix, Kleisli is ArrowEverything)
- Arrow could theoretically extend Applicative as well. Currently I have a method on Arrow returning that Applicative, because it looks like type curring makes inheritance impossible here.
- Are there other non-obvious "connections" (like Arrow->Applicative) I'm missing?
- Which "useful" type classes are missing in this hierarchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should make sure to consult the [typeclassopedia](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/call-for-contributions-second-edition-of-the-typeclassopedia/).
2. Edward Kmett has been doing yeoman's work in trying to construct a rich, sane, hierarchy of core classes, starting with semigroups and moving forward. It's worth corresponding with him directly, but take a look at [semigroupoids](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-1.2.2) and the many related packages he's uploaded for some pointers:

Comment: Of course I know the "original" typeclassopedia, but the links look very promising.